# I/O Error: Software caused connection abort: recv failed

Tags: sockets, tcp

Platform: Window 2003 Server (64 bit), JBOSS 4.0.2, SQL Server 2005

On our production Environment, the JBOSS Application suddenly stops without any reason.
In JBOSS log, it shows following error while retriving data from SQL Server 2005.

## JBOSS ERROR LOG

> java.sql.SQLException: I/O Error:
>   Software caused connection abort: recv
>   failed    at
>   net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.nextToken(TdsCore.java:2277)
>     at
>   net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.getNextRow(TdsCore.java:761)

When we try to restart JBOSS application, It throws same error while fetching data from SQL Server 2005.

```
CallableStatement stm = dbConn.prepareCall("{call getProjectData()}");
ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery();
while(rs.next() ) { //  ***Here Application throws error***
    System.out.println("test");
}
```

Note: Application is able to connect SQL Server and execute Query. But Application is not able to fetch data from ResultSet.
If we restart the machine on which JBOSS is deployed, then it works fine.

What could be reason for such strange behaviour? Any suggestion will be great help.....